# Cant seem to decompile "PYC" After running it through pyinstxtractor

Tags: python-3.x, reverse-engineering, pyc

pyinstxtractor runs to completion without problem, and then suggests to decompress the PYC to get the final .PY file (my goal)

However when I tried to use uncompyle2, uncompyle6, and plethora of other tools none of them worked. (Magic Number Mismatch!) Which means that the file outputted is not a .PYC file...

I opened the outputted file with a hex editor and I can see the source code decoded from hex however Im not able to extract that code in an efficient manner.. It's filled with .'s which should probably be spaces and indentation etc. However nothing i seem to do is able to succesffuly retrieve the source code from hex, or "PYC"

Help?