# (Python) pyinstxtractor does not produce any .py or .pyc files - how to convert the blank file to a .pyc?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, decompiler, pyc

I used pyinstaller to compile `hello_world.py` to `hello_world.exe`. When I run [pyinstxtractor](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor) on the .exe file, I get a large number of files. I have two problems, the second arose trying to fix the first:

- pyinstxtractor does not produce any `.py` or `.pyc` files. It produces a large number of files but the only one of interest ([source](https://hshrzd.wordpress.com/2018/01/26/solving-a-pyinstaller-compiled-crackme/)) is the `hello_world` file with no extension.
- This `hello_world` file appears to be a .pyc file without the magic number. Using the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833455/how-to-find-out-the-magic-number-for-the-pyc-header-in-python-3) showed that "my" magic number is (in hex) `0x550d0d0a`. I viewed the `hello_world` file in hex using the `ASCII --> Hex` tool in Notepad++ and put the magic number at the start. I then renamed this file to `hello_world.pyc` and run it through [uncompyle6](https://pypi.org/project/uncompyle6/). This did not work and gave an error: `ImportError: Unknown magic number 13621 in hello_world.pyc`.

(Related questions, but no-one answered/replied: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606219/cant-seem-to-decompile-pyc-after-running-it-through-pyinstxtractor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36581073/exe-to-python-with-pyinstaller))

Can anyone offer a solution to **either** one of these problems, so that I can get `.py` files from `.exe` files compiled by pyinstaller again? Noting that other programs such as [unpy2exe](https://github.com/matiasb/unpy2exe) do not work on pyinstaller `.exe`'s.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: PyInstxtractor author here. If you're using the latest version, there's no need to manually fix the magic number. Check the [Wiki](https://github.com/extremecoders-re/pyinstxtractor/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#do-i-need-to-fix-the-header-of-the-extracted-pycs). However, do note that you must use the same version of Python which was used to build the executable.

Comment: Thankyou! It turns out I was using an old version from sourcefourge, my problem is fixed now